# Eliminating dups in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am stumped.   I have done everything I can to remove duplicates but I still have one.  I thought the Distinct would take care of this but maybe the admitDate is also distinct.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      p.mrn, 
  p.id, 
      v.PatientID,
      p.firstname, 
      p.lastname, 
      p.dob, 
--     s.SmokeStatus,  
--     v.VisitNo, 
--     s.VisitID,
--     v.ID,
   v.AdmitedDate

FROM
      tblPatient p 
      JOIN tblPatientVisit v ON p.id = v.PatientID
      JOIN tblPatientSmokingScreenOrder s ON v.id = s.VisitID
WHERE 
      isdate(p.DOB) = 1 
      AND CONVERT(date,p.DOB) <'12/10/2000' 
  AND isdate(v.AdmitedDate) = 1 
      AND CONVERT(date,v.AdmitedDate) > '06/16/2013 00:00' 
 -- AND s.TobaccoType IN ('Cigarettes','Cigars','Pipes')
  AND v.PatientType IN ('I', 'EO')
  AND NOT EXISTS (select null from 
                   tblPatientVisit
                   where v.PatientId = p.id
                  and v.PatientType = 'O')

    order by p.MRN


 MRN     ID   Patient ID LastN   FirstN   DOB             AdmitDate
 0015536    132 132 TINKER  BELL    04/20/1963  09/06/2013 14:47
 0015537    133 133 CHEF    RAMSEY  11/02/1974  08/30/2013 11:41
 0015537    133 133 CHEF    RAMSEY  11/02/1974  09/06/2013 14:42
 0015538    134 134 BARRY   MANILOW 06/17/1943  08/30/2013 11:51
```

Chef Ramsey should not list twice.  Since I have a distinct I thought it would only pull one of the 0015537.

Comment: Is Chef Ramsey in the `tblPatientVisit` table twice (different admit dates)? If so, you need to employ either `MIN()` or `MAX()` to get only one record for him.

Comment: As soon as a patient has more than one visit, you are going to have the same patient appear twice.  If you only want him to appear once, you can't pull every admit date the way you are trying.

Comment: Distinct takes unique values over all the columns you've selected - as you have two different `AdmitDate` values, that's why you get two rows. Try grouping by the other columns and using an aggregate on your `AdmitDate` column depending on your requirements (take the min admittance date, max date etc.)

Comment: Based on the syntax this appears to be SQL Server, so I added that as a tag

Answer (score 1):

The distinct is for *all* the fields, not just a few of them.  If you notice, some of the other columns are different.  Here is one way to fix your problem.  It pulls a random row for each `mrn`, using the `row_number()` function to add a sequential number.

You have some issues with dates as well.  The way it is set up, it might get a type conversion error on the dates.  The solution to this is to use a `case` statement.  It is also better to use ANSI standard date formats for date constants:

```
with t as (
      SELECT p.mrn, p.id, v.PatientID, p.firstname, p.lastname, p.dob, v.AdmitedDate,
             row_number() over (partition by p.mrn order by newid()) as seqnum
      FROM tblPatient p  oin
           tblPatientVisit v ON p.id = v.PatientID
           tblPatientSmokingScreenOrder s ON v.id = s.VisitID
      WHERE (case when isdate(p.DOB) = 1 then CONVERT(date, p.DOB) end) < '2000-12-10' and
            (case when isdate(v.AdmitedDate) = 1 then CONVERT(date, v.AdmitedDate) end) > '2013-06-16' and
            v.PatientType IN ('I', 'EO') and
            NOT EXISTS (select 1 from 
                        tblPatientVisit
                        where v.PatientId = p.id and v.PatientType = 'O'
                       )
    )
select t.*
from t
where seqnum = 1
order by p.MRN;
```